# Why SolrCloud slows down when one instance killed?

Tags: performance, solrcloud

I am using SolrCloud (version 4.7.1) with 4 instances and embedded ZooKeeper (test environment).

- When I simulate failure of one of the instances, the indexing speed goes from 4 seconds to 17 seconds.
- It goes back to 4 seconds after the instance is brought back to life.
- Search speed is not affected.
- Our production environment shows similar behavior (only the configuration is more complex).

Is this normal or did I miss some configuration option?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to having Zookeeper embedded in Solr cluster.
Please try with external zookeeper. This setup give the expected results.